# How would I get this output?

Tags: java

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
public class EuclidGCD {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner kbd = new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.print ("Enter First Number: ");
  int n1 = kbd.nextInt();
  System.out.print ("Enter Second Number: ");
  int n2 = kbd.nextInt();
  int gcd = 1;
  int k = 2;
  while (k <= n1 && k <= n2){
   if (n1 % k == 0 && n2 % k == 0)
   gcd = k ;
  k ++;
  }
  System.out.println("The GCD of " + n1 + " and " + n2 + " is " + gcd);

 }

}
```

so everything works but I realized that I do not want a neg number if a negative number is entered I want the output POSITIVE NUMBERS ONLY so would I need another while loop?

Comment: I would suggest just getting the absolute value of `n1` and `n2` before you factor the GCD.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a if statement checking if n1 and n2 are  positive, and only excuted the rest of your code if they are. You shouldn't need another while loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print ("Enter First Number: ");
        int n1 = kbd.nextInt();
        System.out.print ("Enter Second Number: ");
        int n2 = kbd.nextInt();
        if(n1 < 0 || n2 < 0 ){
            System.out.println("POSITIVE NUMBERS ONLY ");

        }else{
            int gcd = 1;
            int k = 2;
            while (k <= n1 && k <= n2){
                if (n1 % k == 0 && n2 % k == 0)
                gcd = k ;
            k ++;
            }
            System.out.println("The GCD of " + n1 + " and " + n2 + " is " + gcd);
        }
    }
```

Comment: so after i have declared n2?

Comment: cause i put a while (n1 < 0 && n2 < 0){
   System.out.print("POSITIVE NUMBERS ONLY"); after int2 and the GCD of -5 and 15 is returned as 1 when it should be POSITIVE NUMBERS ONLY

Comment: i just want to enter two numbers and then output postive numbers only if a negative number is used

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I didn't read what you wanted to happen when you got a negative number. My previous code was trying to keep prompting the user for more numbers until it got a positive one. I've updated my answer for what you actually wanted :)